# ASP.NET Login store userdata

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Im a newcommer in ASP.NET (Switched from Java/PHP) And tried to create a simple Login.
Now i get Stuck, are there any Sessions in ASP.NET to store if the User is logged in? Or how does the ASP.NET World store this information?

Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Read more on asp.net [session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx). Generally we uses Form-authentication to authenticate and authorize the request in ASP.NET.

Articles/posts:

1. [An Overview of Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb)
2. [Using Forms Authentication in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150650/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110701-1.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can use session as well as cookie.

For cookies read this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Beginners_Cookies.aspx

For sessions assign like this

```
Session["adminid"]="value";
```

and retrieve value like this

> string sessionval=Session["adminid"].toString();